# Celery work process consumes 100% CPU after running for several days

Tags: python, celery, celeryd

I submitted one issue to Celery project, see the details here: [Celery worker process CPU 100%](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1558)

After running Celery worker process for some days, we found that the Python process consumes the 100% CPU load. I used the strace to dump the runtime stacktrace, I found that the CPU 100% process continuously pool and read. It must be related with the Consumer.consume_message.

Anyone has ideas?

Comment: Without any source code this is going to be tough to answer.